# Get specific parameterized type with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I know that i can get parameterized types of a class in the following way:

```
Type[] genericInterfaces = getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
for (Type genericInterface : genericInterfaces) {
    if (genericInterface instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) genericInterface;
        // do something 
    }
}
```

But suppose i need to check for a specific parameterized type, like `List<T>`. The `type` offers `getRawType().getTypeName()` and i could compare that to the class name (or simple class name, i am not sure) of `List`. Is this the right way to go?

**Update:**

To be more specific: How can I get all beans implementing a specific interface, then register the generic type parameter on a map as key, the bean as value.

Comment: Compare the `Class<T>` itself, don't compare the names.

Comment: @Michael Can you explain further? I need to get hold of the Paramerized Type object of a specific class, if it exists.

Comment: What exacly you want to do? for `MyClass implements List<String>` this `ParameterizedType#getRawType` would represent `List.class` and  `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` would represent `String.class` (note that in many places you can find types like `List<? extends String>` or generic type may reference other generic type, like `MyClass<X> implements List<X>` and then `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` would not be of `Class` type)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where is the other type coming from? What kind of `Type` is it?

Comment: @GotoFinal I need to check if any class implements a generic interface and then get hold of of the generic type parameters class.

Comment: @Glains and why you need that?

Comment: @GotoFinal Get all beans implementing that interface, then register  the type parameter on a map as key, the bean as value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis See my update

Comment: @Glains then you can't do anything like that using typical reflections, as java does not provide standard way to lookup for types in runtime, but they are libraries for that like `Reflections` that just scans class path and manually "load" all class files that it can find to get ones that implements given type. (it does not load all classes to JVM). You can also use annotation processing to generate code for each class on compile time.

Comment: @GotoFinal It seems I forgot, you are absolutely right here. I'll use an annotation and process it at runtime. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach only work when `List<T>` is a direct interface and T is explicit.

You can use my utility class [`GenericUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/297b21df13ebe25e991ec3741af21b3592e92375/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/GenericUtil.java#L106)

```
// your approach only works for this situation
class Foo implements List<String>{}
// your approach not work in these situations
class A<T> implements List<T>{}
class B extends A<Integer>{}
class C extends A<A<C>>{}

GenericUtil.getGenericTypes(Foo.class, List.class); // {String}
GenericUtil.getGenericTypes(A.class, List.class); // {T}
GenericUtil.getGenericTypes(B.class, List.class); // {Integer.class}
GenericUtil.getGenericTypes(C.class, List.class); // {A<C>}
```

Comment: So, there is a way to get the type parameter, thanks for your help! My beans are explicit and Spring has to do it somehow as well for repositories.